# How can I make a popup banner display once every 12 hours per user with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Using the code below, currently my popup will come back after closing it on every page reload or any new page I navigate to on my site.
Utilizing this code, could someone please provide me with an example of how I can make this popup banner display once every 12 hours per user instead?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  var headerBar = $(".top-header-bar");
  var notificationBar = $(".heder-popup");
  if(notificationBar.is(":visible")) {
    headerBar.addClass("custom-header-top");
  } else {
    headerBar.removeClass("custom-header-top");
  }
  $( "#popup-close" ).click(function() {
    headerBar.removeClass("custom-header-top");
    notificationBar.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Set a cookie that expires in 12 hours, and check for the cookie on page load

Comment: @MosheGross I read up on that. Still cannot figure out how to integrate it successfully into my current code.